# Can't perform matrix multiplication on float matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

Today as I'm trying to implement linear regression by hand, I encountered an issue in numpy that stops me from performing the intended matrix multiplication. Because the two matrix contains float numbers (not sure if that is the issue), the notebook kept on returning

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TqoORBOlo2F4lwHdURh6MZJP1D4VSbqb?usp=sharing) is the notebook at the data I used, please help!

Comment: to help us help you and the community please include a minimal reproducible example of your code _here_ as text - that will allow users to copy and paste to try as well as search it

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use `np.matmul` or `@` (shorthand) rather than the `*` shorthand, which makes soft-copies duplicates in a Python list (and so can't create a fractional number, only integral ones)

See the notes in the numpy.dot docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: `@` won't work with `[1,2,3]@1.2` either.  In any case he's try to do math on a list.

Comment: surely so, but they specifically defined that they were using `numpy` both in the question and tags, so they likely have two errors .. it's hard to say until they include a minimal example though..

Answer (score 0):

Code and traceback should be part of your question.  But this error is produced by an expression like

```
In [99]: [1,2,3]*1.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-99-fdfde54247f2>", line 1, in <module>
    [1,2,3]*1.2
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

`[1,2,3]` a list is a sequence.  `multiply` is only defined for an integer, and means replication.

At this point in the code you aren't using `numpy`.